# VSCode C/C++ Extension Multi-project include path wrong

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code, cmake, gnu-make

I have a Multi-Project setup with cross compilers using tensorflow-lite-micro (TFLM). TFLM generates its own makefile to build the library and the application with the riscv32-gnu toolchain. The project is structured as follow:

```
├── build
│   ├── build.ninja
│   ├── CMakeCache.txt
│   ├── CMakeFiles
│   │   ├── 3.20.3
│   │   ├── cmake.check_cache
│   │   ├── CMakeOutput.log
│   │   ├── CMakeTmp
│   │   ├── rules.ninja
│   │   └── TargetDirectories.txt
│   └── cmake_install.cmake
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── LICENSE
├── Makefile
├── README_MAKE.md
├── src
│   ├── detection_responder.cc
│   ├── detection_responder.h
│   ├── entry.s
│   ├── image_provider.cc
│   ├── image_provider.h
│   ├── main.cc
│   ├── model_settings.cc
│   ├── model_settings.h
│   ├── person_detect_model_data.cc
│   └── person_detect_model_data.h
├── tensorflow
│   └── lite
│       ├── c
│       ├── core
│       ├── kernels
│       ├── micro
│       ├── portable_type_to_tflitetype.h
│       └── schema
└── third_party
    ├── flatbuffers
    │   ├── include
    │   └── LICENSE.txt
    ├── gemmlowp
    │   ├── fixedpoint
    │   ├── internal
    │   └── LICENSE
    └── ruy
        └── ruy
```

Moreover, the cmake file which delegates the build process to the Makefile is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(TFLITE_MEMORY_ANALYSIS)

include_directories(.)
include_directories(third_party/flatbuffers/include)

add_custom_target(MEMORY_ANALYSIS_ELF
                   COMMAND make all -j12
                   WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```

The project is building without any problems but the C/C++ extension of vscode does not find the headers from tensorflow.

[image]

Moreover the following line works for the code in the `src` directory.

```
#include "../tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_interpreter.h"
```

My `c_cpp_properties.json` use mostly default values except the `compilerPath`

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/local/bin/riscv32-unknown-elf-g++",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++11",
            "intelliSenseMode": "${default}",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools",
            "forcedInclude": []
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I used the logging feature of the C/C++ extensions and I think the path resolving isn't quite working as expected but I am not sure and I don't know how to proceed further or how to fix it. This is very annoying because I work deep inside the tensorflow library and without Intellisense I have to switch to another IDE which I don't want. As far as I understand the loggs the `${workspaceFolder}` variable from the config is not pointing to the project root but to `build/CMakeFiles` which is wrong because the Makefile is responsible for building.

```
Custom browse configuration received: {
  "browsePath": [
    "/home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/build/CMakeFiles"
  ],
  "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/c++",
  "compilerArgs": []
}
Custom browse configuration received: {
  "browsePath": [
    "/home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/build/CMakeFiles"
  ],
  "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/c++",
  "compilerArgs": []
}
cpptools/didChangeCppProperties
Attempting to get defaults from C++ compiler in "compilerPath" property: '/usr/bin/clang'
Compiler query command line: "/usr/bin/clang" -std=c++14 -Wp,-v -E -dD -x c++ -m64 -fno-blocks /dev/null
terminating child process: 9808
Attempting to get defaults from C compiler in "compilerPath" property: '/usr/bin/clang'
Compiler query command line: "/usr/bin/clang" -std=c17 -Wp,-v -E -dD -x c -m64 -fno-blocks /dev/null
terminating child process: 9809
  Folder: /include/ will be indexed
  Folder: /usr/include/ will be indexed
  Folder: /usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/ will be indexed
  Folder: /usr/local/include/ will be indexed
  Folder: /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/riscv_vp/ will be indexed
cpptools/didChangeCustomBrowseConfiguration
Attempting to get defaults from C++ compiler in "compilerPath" property: '/usr/bin/c++'
Querying compiler for default C++ language standard using command line: "/usr/bin/c++" -x c++ -E -dM /dev/null
terminating child process: 9810
Detected language standard version: gnu++17
Querying compiler for default C language standard using command line: "/usr/bin/c++" -x c -E -dM /dev/null
terminating child process: 9814
Detected language standard version: gnu17
Querying compiler's default target using command line: "/usr/bin/c++" -dumpmachine
Compiler returned default target value: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

terminating child process: 9816
Compiler query command line: "/usr/bin/c++" -std=c++17 -Wp,-v -E -dD -x c++ -m64  /dev/null
terminating child process: 9817
  Folder: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include/ will be indexed
  Folder: /usr/local/include/ will be indexed
  Folder: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include-fixed/ will be indexed
  Folder: /usr/include/ will be indexed
  Folder: /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/build/CMakeFiles/ will be indexed
cpptools/didChangeCppProperties
Attempting to get defaults from C compiler in "compilerPath" property: '/usr/local/bin/riscv32-unknown-elf-g++'
Querying compiler for default C++ language standard using command line: "/usr/local/bin/riscv32-unknown-elf-g++" -x c++ -E -dM /dev/null
terminating child process: 9821
Detected language standard version: gnu++14
Querying compiler for default C language standard using command line: "/usr/local/bin/riscv32-unknown-elf-g++" -x c -E -dM /dev/null
terminating child process: 9829
Detected language standard version: gnu17
Querying compiler's default target using command line: "/usr/local/bin/riscv32-unknown-elf-g++" -dumpmachine
Compiler returned default target value: riscv32-unknown-elf

terminating child process: 9836
Unhandled default compiler target value detected: riscv32-unknown-elf

Compiler query command line: "/usr/local/bin/riscv32-unknown-elf-g++" -std=c17 -Wp,-v -E -dD -x c -m64  /dev/null
Failed to query compiler. Falling back to 32-bit intelliSenseMode.
terminating child process: 9837
Compiler query command line: "/usr/local/bin/riscv32-unknown-elf-g++" -std=c17 -Wp,-v -E -dD -x c -m32  /dev/null
Failed to query compiler. Falling back to no bitness.
terminating child process: 9838
Compiler query command line: "/usr/local/bin/riscv32-unknown-elf-g++" -std=c17 -Wp,-v -E -dD -x c   /dev/null
terminating child process: 9839
Code browsing service initialized
Attempting to get defaults from C++ compiler in "compilerPath" property: '/usr/local/bin/riscv32-unknown-elf-g++'
Compiler query command line: "/usr/local/bin/riscv32-unknown-elf-g++" -std=c++11 -Wp,-v -E -dD -x c++ -m64  /dev/null
Populate include completion cache.
Failed to query compiler. Falling back to 32-bit intelliSenseMode.
terminating child process: 9841
Compiler query command line: "/usr/local/bin/riscv32-unknown-elf-g++" -std=c++11 -Wp,-v -E -dD -x c++ -m32  /dev/null
Failed to query compiler. Falling back to no bitness.
terminating child process: 9843
Compiler query command line: "/usr/local/bin/riscv32-unknown-elf-g++" -std=c++11 -Wp,-v -E -dD -x c++   /dev/null
terminating child process: 9844
  Folder: /usr/local/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/10.2.0/include/ will be indexed
  Folder: /usr/local/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/10.2.0/include-fixed/ will be indexed
  Folder: /usr/local/riscv32-unknown-elf/include/ will be indexed
  Folder: /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/ will be indexed
cpptools/didChangeCustomBrowseConfiguration
Attempting to get defaults from C++ compiler in "compilerPath" property: '/usr/bin/c++'
Compiler query command line: "/usr/bin/c++" -std=c++17 -Wp,-v -E -dD -x c++ -m64  /dev/null
terminating child process: 9846
  Folder: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include/ will be indexed
  Folder: /usr/local/include/ will be indexed
  Folder: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include-fixed/ will be indexed
  Folder: /usr/include/ will be indexed
  Folder: /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/build/CMakeFiles/ will be indexed
textDocument/didOpen: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
cpptools/activeDocumentChange: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
cpptools/resumeParsing
cpptools/textEditorSelectionChange
cpptools/textEditorSelectionChange
cpptools/clearCustomConfigurations
Checking for syntax errors: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
Populate include completion cache.
cpptools/clearCustomConfigurations
cpptools/getDocumentSymbols: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc (id: 2)
cpptools/getDocumentSymbols
cpptools/getCodeActions: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc (id: 3)
cpptools/getFoldingRanges: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc (id: 4)
Discovering files...
  Processing folder (recursive): /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include/
cpptools/getSemanticTokens: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc (id: 5)
  Processing folder (recursive): /usr/local/include/
  Processing folder (recursive): /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include-fixed/
  Processing folder (recursive): /usr/include/
sending compilation args for /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
  include: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0
  include: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  include: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/backward
  include: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include
  include: /usr/local/include
  include: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include-fixed
  include: /usr/include
  define: __STDC__=1
  define: __cplusplus=201703L
  define: __STDC_UTF_16__=1
  define: __STDC_UTF_32__=1
Custom configuration provider 'CMake Tools' registered
  define: __STDC_HOSTED__=1
  define: __GNUC__=11
  define: __GNUC_MINOR__=1
  define: __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__=0
  define: __VERSION__="11.1.0"
  define: __ATOMIC_RELAXED=0
  define: __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST=5
  define: __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE=2
  define: __ATOMIC_RELEASE=3
  define: __ATOMIC_ACQ_REL=4
  define: __ATOMIC_CONSUME=1
  define: __pic__=2
  define: __PIC__=2
  define: __pie__=2
  define: __PIE__=2
  define: __FINITE_MATH_ONLY__=0
  define: _LP64=1
  define: __LP64__=1
  define: __SIZEOF_INT__=4
  define: __SIZEOF_LONG__=8
  define: __SIZEOF_LONG_LONG__=8
  define: __SIZEOF_SHORT__=2
  define: __SIZEOF_FLOAT__=4
  define: __SIZEOF_DOUBLE__=8
  define: __SIZEOF_LONG_DOUBLE__=16
  define: __SIZEOF_SIZE_T__=8
  define: __CHAR_BIT__=8
  define: __BIGGEST_ALIGNMENT__=16
Custom browse configuration received: {
  "browsePath": [
    "/home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/build/CMakeFiles"
  ],
  "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/c++",
  "compilerArgs": []
}
Custom browse configuration received: {
  "browsePath": [
    "/home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/build/CMakeFiles"
  ],
  "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/c++",
  "compilerArgs": []
}
  define: __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__=1234
  define: __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__=4321
  define: __ORDER_PDP_ENDIAN__=3412
  ...
  other: --g++
  other: --gnu_version=110100
  stdver: c++17
  intelliSenseMode: linux-gcc-x64
Shutting down IntelliSense server: /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
sending compilation args for /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
  include: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0
  include: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  include: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/backward
  include: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include
  include: /usr/local/include
  include: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include-fixed
  include: /usr/include
  define: __STDC__=1
  define: __cplusplus=201703L
  ...
  other: --g++
  other: --gnu_version=110100
  stdver: c++17
  intelliSenseMode: linux-gcc-x64
Checking for syntax errors: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
Shutting down IntelliSense server: /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
sending compilation args for /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
  include: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0
  include: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  include: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/backward
  include: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include
  include: /usr/local/include
  include: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include-fixed
  include: /usr/include
  define: __STDC__=1
  define: __cplusplus=201703L
  ...
  other: --g++
  other: --gnu_version=110100
  stdver: c++17
  intelliSenseMode: linux-gcc-x64
Queueing IntelliSense update for files in translation unit of: /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
cpptools/finishUpdateSquiggles
Error squiggle count: 47
Error squiggles will be disabled in: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
terminating child process: 9971
Update IntelliSense time (sec): 1.179
cpptools/didChangeCppProperties
cpptools/pauseParsing
cpptools/didChangeCppProperties
cpptools/pauseParsing
cpptools/clearCustomConfigurations
Shutting down IntelliSense server: /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
Checking for syntax errors: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
cpptools/clearCustomConfigurations
cpptools/queryTranslationUnitSource: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc (id: 6)
cpptools/didChangeCustomBrowseConfiguration
Attempting to get defaults from C++ compiler in "compilerPath" property: '/usr/bin/c++'
cpptools/didChangeCustomBrowseConfiguration
Attempting to get defaults from C++ compiler in "compilerPath" property: '/usr/bin/c++'
sending compilation args for /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
  include: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0
  include: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  include: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/backward
  include: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include
  include: /usr/local/include
  include: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include-fixed
  include: /usr/include
  define: __STDC__=1
  define: __cplusplus=201703L
  ...
  other: --g++
  other: --gnu_version=110100
  stdver: c++17
  intelliSenseMode: linux-gcc-x64
Checking for syntax errors: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
Shutting down IntelliSense server: /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
sending compilation args for /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
  include: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0
  include: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  include: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/backward
  include: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include
  include: /usr/local/include
  include: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include-fixed
  include: /usr/include
  define: __STDC__=1
  define: __cplusplus=201703L
  ...
  other: --g++
  other: --gnu_version=110100
  stdver: c++17
  intelliSenseMode: linux-gcc-x64
Queueing IntelliSense update for files in translation unit of: /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
cpptools/fileCreated: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/build/CMakeFiles/TargetDirectories.txt
cpptools/fileCreated: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/build/CMakeFiles/rules.ninja
cpptools/fileCreated: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/build/build.ninja
cpptools/fileCreated: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/build/.cmake/api/v1/reply/index-2021-06-28T09-06-46-0676.json
cpptools/fileDeleted: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/build/.cmake/api/v1/reply/index-2021-06-28T08-40-39-0051.json
cpptools/fileCreated: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/riscv_vp/build/CMakeFiles/TargetDirectories.txt
cpptools/fileCreated: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/riscv_vp/build/compile_commands.json
cpptools/fileCreated: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/riscv_vp/build/CMakeFiles/rules.ninja
cpptools/fileCreated: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/riscv_vp/build/build.ninja
cpptools/fileCreated: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/riscv_vp/build/.cmake/api/v1/reply/index-2021-06-28T09-06-46-0920.json
cpptools/fileDeleted: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/riscv_vp/build/.cmake/api/v1/reply/index-2021-06-28T08-40-39-0229.json
Checking for syntax errors: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
Queueing IntelliSense update for files in translation unit of: /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
cpptools/finishUpdateSquiggles
Error squiggle count: 47
Error squiggles will be disabled in: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
Update IntelliSense time (sec): 0.103
cpptools/resumeParsing
cpptools/resumeParsing
cpptools/clearCustomConfigurations
Shutting down IntelliSense server: /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
Checking for syntax errors: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
cpptools/clearCustomConfigurations
cpptools/queryTranslationUnitSource: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc (id: 7)
cpptools/getDocumentSymbols: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc (id: 8)
cpptools/getDocumentSymbols
sending compilation args for /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
  include: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0
  include: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  include: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/backward
  include: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include
  include: /usr/local/include
  include: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include-fixed
  include: /usr/include
  define: __STDC__=1
  define: __cplusplus=201703L
  ...
  other: --g++
  other: --gnu_version=110100
  stdver: c++17
  intelliSenseMode: linux-gcc-x64
Checking for syntax errors: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
Shutting down IntelliSense server: /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
sending compilation args for /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
  include: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0
  include: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  include: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/backward
  include: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include
  include: /usr/local/include
  include: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include-fixed
  include: /usr/include
  define: __STDC__=1
  define: __cplusplus=201703L
  ...
  other: --g++
  other: --gnu_version=110100
  stdver: c++17
  intelliSenseMode: linux-gcc-x64
Queueing IntelliSense update for files in translation unit of: /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
cpptools/clearCustomConfigurations
Checking for syntax errors: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
cpptools/clearCustomConfigurations
cpptools/queryTranslationUnitSource: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc (id: 9)
Shutting down IntelliSense server: /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
sending compilation args for /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
  include: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0
  include: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  include: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/backward
  include: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include
  include: /usr/local/include
  include: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include-fixed
  include: /usr/include
  define: __STDC__=1
  define: __cplusplus=201703L
  ...
  other: --g++
  other: --gnu_version=110100
  stdver: c++17
  intelliSenseMode: linux-gcc-x64
Checking for syntax errors: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
Queueing IntelliSense update for files in translation unit of: /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
cpptools/getCodeActions: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc (id: 10)
0 include path suggestion(s) discovered.
cpptools/getSemanticTokens: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc (id: 11)
cpptools/getFoldingRanges: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc (id: 12)
  Processing folder (recursive): /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/build/CMakeFiles/
  Processing folder (recursive): /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include/
  Processing folder (recursive): /usr/local/include/
  Processing folder (recursive): /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include-fixed/
  Processing folder (recursive): /usr/include/
cpptools/finishUpdateSquiggles
Error squiggle count: 47
Error squiggles will be disabled in: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc
Update IntelliSense time (sec): 0.545
cpptools/getSemanticTokens: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc (id: 13)
cpptools/getFoldingRanges: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc (id: 14)
cpptools/getCodeActions: file:///home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/src/main.cc (id: 15)
0 include path suggestion(s) discovered.
  Processing folder (recursive): /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/build/CMakeFiles/
  Discovering files: 81798 file(s) processed
  0 file(s) removed from database
Done discovering files.
Parsing remaining files...
  Parsing: 0 files(s) processed
Done parsing remaining files.
Populate include completion cache.
Discovering files...
  Processing folder (recursive): /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include/
  Processing folder (recursive): /usr/local/include/
  Processing folder (recursive): /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include-fixed/
  Processing folder (recursive): /usr/include/
  Processing folder (recursive): /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/build/CMakeFiles/
  Processing folder (recursive): /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include/
  Processing folder (recursive): /usr/local/include/
  Processing folder (recursive): /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/include-fixed/
  Processing folder (recursive): /usr/include/
  Processing folder (recursive): /home/alfr02/Dev/hwaccel/memory_analysis/build/CMakeFiles/
  Discovering files: 81798 file(s) processed
  7 file(s) removed from database
Done discovering files.
Parsing remaining files...
  Parsing: 0 files(s) processed
Done parsing remaining files.
Database safe to open
```

Thx for the help and sorry for typos, english is not my native language :D

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is like a rubber-duck thing. I found a fix by writing this question but maybe it helps others with a similar problem.

Just removing the line

```
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools",
```

from `c_cpp_properties.json` fixed the issue. It seems like this line indirectly alters the includePath to the CMake-Build directory.